# Why files are being deleted while trying to open them?

Tags: filemanager

It has been two days while trying to open a file or a folder or even select a file by clicking, it is being sent to trash.I am now using Ubuntu 18.10. The file manager is Nautilus. The file system is ext4 with lvm. It is not a networked system. Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Check your keyboard, a bad delete button may cause it. Try removing the keyboard.

Comment: I have checked. It seems to be completely okay. Again before the file being deleted sometimes it shows a dialogue box saying file can't be opened.

Comment: Have the file system on your drive checked. It might be corrupt.

Comment: How to check this?

Comment: Check your file-system with a `fsck` command (file-system check).  You haven't given us any specific details so we can only provide generic help (ie. we don't know your release of Ubuntu, what file-manager you thus mean (ie. nautilus, thunar, pcmanfm, pcmanfm-qt, dolphin..) nor what file-system you are talking about).  If it's a network or shared drive, the file could have been deleted by another process/user & thus the clicking on the file is causing the changed *fs* to be noticed & it's not deleted by your click, but it causes it to be noticed as changed/umounted/etc.

Comment: I am using Nautilus file manager. The file system is ext4 with lvm. The Ubuntu release is 18.10. The device is not a networked device.Actually the files are being deleted while I am trying to open them.

Comment: Is it a specific file type (PDF, .docx, text) that gets deleted or just any file?

Comment: No it is not any specific file type. All types of files are being deleted while trying to open.

Comment: open nautilus from command line, when the issue occurs check the terminal. it will likely show the error or show a message.